# Похожесть строковых значений, степень сходства строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Когда необходимо выбрать несколько максимально похожих записей таблицы БД к тем данным, что ввёл пользователь?

Нужно просто просуммировать произведения **"похожести"** полей на их **"важность"**. После чего, сортировать по убыванию суммы и выбрать N первых записей. Важность будет пропорциональна длине строки, а вот над похожестью надо ещё заморочиться.

Не помню, когда и как, но я слышал о существовании функции, которая сравнивает две строки и возвращает значение между нулём и единицей, что мне и нужно.

В гугле не нахожу, потому и спрашиваю. Если кто-то знает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно Вы ищите функцию `MATCH`? Или Что-то из разряда функции Левенштейна.

Comment: Да, похоже именно это я видел, но не мог вспомнить! Спасибо)